# HR Easy Blog WordPress theme logo removal

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Currently for a blog of mine I'm using HR Easy Blog WordPress theme. There I have a problem on how to remove the HR Easy Blog logo on the home page. I tried several methods but nothing worked for me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcCe7.png)

Comment: You want change logo image or remove whole logo part?

Comment: I want to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to your theme's `header.php` file and remove or comment below code:

```
<div class="header hidden-xs clearfix">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="logo pull-left">
    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>"><?php $logo = (get_option('hires_logo') <> '') ? get_option('hires_logo') : get_template_directory_uri().'/images/logo.png'; ?><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" id="logo"/></a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <?php /* Home Ad #1 */
        if( get_option('hires_ad_480_60_enable') == 'on'){
            echo '<div class="pull-right top-ads">';
            echo get_option('hires_ad_480_60_code');
            echo "</div>"; 
        } ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```